# How to solve Failed to create a Maven Project-Could not resolve archetype?

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, virtualenv

[image: Maven Error]

I'm working on a virtual machine and I have faced some errors after installing eclipse. The errors appeared due to some certificates that eclipse and maven could not import. However I did import the certificates correctly with following command:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin>keytool -import -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\lib\security\cacerts" -alias maven3 -file C:\Users\950002\Desktop\quickstart.cer

But the problem still remains. Please check the screen shots attached above on image description.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to remove all the comments from my settings.xml file in maven. Specially in proxy and mirrors. Then made sure that eclipse would point to this settings with changes made and that's it. It works now.